# Network profile list same account twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile

Why does the network profile (account tab) for [this user](https://stackexchange.com/users/4720877/suji?tab=accounts) list the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) account twice?

[image: Network profile - accounts]

Comment: the fact that the number of questions and answers are different makes me think that this is something to do with merging accounts...?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. But it's a bug right?

Comment: yep - seems like a bug.

Comment: [Zombie account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4808848/) - somehow it's still linked behind the scenes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I cannot see the linked user account(!). But if "zombie account" means what I think it does, then .. let's say I'm not surprised.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå it's still linked in the Stack Overflow profile as 1 rep account, I don't have magic powers. It means a deleted (dead) account which is still kept alive by being listed. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looks like the issue has been resolved after a flag I raised yesterday panned out *helpful*. Can you, as a high-rep user, still see the deleted account/bug? If not, should i delete this question?

Comment: Weird, now there's no trace for either of the account of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The account were (yet another) sock-puppet account belonging to a user serving a 1 year ban for voting irregularities. Maybe the zombie account were deleted in the process?

Comment: Oh, sock puppet to avoid suspension is a big NO NO, no wonder they're nuked.

Comment: -1 for bad question mark drawing. I expect higher quality from your _paintings_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a merge that threw an error - it will be resolved when the user list falls out of cache over the next ~10 minutes.